# Laravel: Something wrong with migration command

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-migrations

I find this one so weird, can you point what am I missing?

I run "php artisan migrate" its working well.

When I do this line "php artisan migrate:refresh" or "php artisan migrate:reset" Error below:

[image]

so I checked the file 2014_10_12_0000 ... it was not all in my files. I only had this file in my migrations folder:
[image]

Can you site what am I missing?

Comment: 2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table is in migration table but not in your directory so you get that result . Please check your migration table in your database

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try running `composer dumpautoload` if you're on Laravel 5+ or `php artisan dump-autoload` if you're on 4.

Happens to me a lot as well. `php artisan migrate` only looks at the files but `php artisan migrate:rollback` or `php artisan migrate:refresh` looks at your autoloaded files.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have deleted migration files AFTER you done your first migration.

L5 comes with 2 migration files out of the box to create a user table and a password reset table.

What `migrate:refresh` does is, it will rollback all migrations that have been migrated (for this you will find a `migrations` table in your database) and migrate everything again.

Now if you have deleted the create_users migration it doesn't know how to rollback.

If you're resetting anyway you can just delete your whole database (including the migrations table) and run `php artisan migrate` again.

And remember not to delete your migration files in the future ;)